# Using any Javascript chart library, is it possible to show data with opacity at certain X?

Tags: javascript, linechart

Using Google Chart, I'm trying to show a line graph that will show one line that can, at a certain X axis, show multiple lines, each of them being with opacity: 0.5.

When the customer hover over a specific line, this line becomes at opacity: 1, giving the feedback it's the line the user is looking at.

The main idea behind it is for a line chart that will show projections of data in the future. All the data until now are certain, so they won't change, but after "today", we will show 3 different lines based on different estimations.

So far I came to this result (https://jsfiddle.net/7nk1odsy/) using Google Charts :

```
google.charts.load('current', {'packages':['corechart']});
google.charts.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);

function drawChart() {
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Sales', { "type": "string", "role": "style" }, 'Forecast 1', { "type": "string", "role": "style" }, 'Forecast 2', { "type": "string", "role": "style" }],
    ['2004',  1000, 'opacity: 1;',      null, 'opacity: 1;',      null, 'opacity: 1;'],
    ['2005',  1170, 'opacity: 1;',      null, 'opacity: 1;',      null, 'opacity: 1;'],
    ['2006',  660, 'opacity: 1;',       660, 'opacity: 0;',      660, 'opacity: 0;'],
    ['2007',  null, 'opacity: .3;',      540, 'opacity: .3;',      720, 'opacity: .3;']
  ]);

  var options = {
    title: 'Company Performance',
    legend: { position: 'bottom' },
    dataOpacity: 0.5
  };

  var chart = new google.visualization.LineChart(document.getElementById('curve_chart'));

  chart.draw(data, options);
}
```

But it's missing the change of opacity to 1 when hovering the line, and ideally, changing the full line (even the first line) to make it look like it's one full line.

How can I do this?

Comment: Yes. And by programming it.

Comment: Wow, the SO community is getting better everyday!

Comment: You have 16k rep, you should know that if you don't show Any code at all, not even a data sample to work with, that your question will not get answered.

Comment: How can I provie a code sample from something I didn't find how to do? I can show some js, but I don't believe an `alert('show graph')` will be useful. On the contrary, this community has been so focused by following the rules that everyone downvote, ask for close, even without reading the question or giving any interest at all on the subject. That's what I get with my 16k experience ...

Comment: It's still primary opinion based and asking for a tool. *sigh* D3 is Very good, but hard to learn and takes alot of code to make. Highcharts is easier, but you need a licence for the pro version. Google charting tools are very nice and handy, but require connection with the google servers. And if the graph is small, just program it yourself in svg and some basic css hover effects.

Comment: It's opinion based because you want to think so. What opinion am I asking? Which is the best tool to do the job? Not at all. Is this a simple coding question? I don't think so. I challenge you to provide with a code sample that target the purpose of StackOverflow: help others, not downvote a question that hasn't a code on it, because, yes, sometime a coding question doesn't require some code, it's called having an open mind.

Comment: (I'm not directly targeting this to you @Shilly, but it's everytime the same, despite asking some legitimate question on a "coding" Q&A).

Comment: I came at this result so far : https://jsfiddle.net/7nk1odsy/. From what I'm looking for, it's missing to change the opacity to 1 on hover, and ideally "glow" the whole line.

Comment: The Stack Overflow forum is to help people find the bugs in THEIR code. If you want to hire a freelancer, there's stack exchange jobs. If you want to talk general programming tips, there's stack exchange programmers, webmasters, software engineering. If there's already so many forums for everything, how hard is it to stick to debugging on SO? Sorry for the rant. More leniant to new ppl, but with 16k rep you should know better, even if you disagree. Thanks for the code, I'll have a look at what we can do with the google options object we can pass into the graph draw function.

Comment: Don't worry about the rant, I didn't take it that way. The most irritating thing is having a downvote without explanation.

Comment: _"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam."_

Comment: @Alnitak I'm was not asking to recommend a library but instead giving the liberty to use any library to help me find a solution.

Comment: I don't see any distinction - you're either asking how to make your currently chosen library do what you need (when it may not even be capable of it), or asking for a library that already does what you need.  The latter is asking for a recommendation.

Comment: I don't see why someone asking a question can't give people the liberty to recommend some lib that does the job. Sorry but sometimes people are too harsh with small things. Why don't we all relax a bit ?

Comment: Ok so apparently it disturb too many peoples if I give some liberty of thinking, so I've updated the question to restrict to one library, Google Chart.

Answer (score 2):

1) Haven't found an exact solution yet, but the following can help you along.

We can target pieces of the svg with css, so we can  just use a hover effect to color the lines. The tricky part is getting the correct element.
Alas, the circle popover and the path aren't in the same container,so navigation is hard.

If the circle is the target, then `circle.parentNode.parentNode.previousSibling` gives you the `<g>` element wrapper containing the line. From there it's the x-th child, with x being the child index of the circle.

This way it is technically possible to navigate to the correct line and restyle it. So one possibility is adding a mouseover handler to the line/circle and navigate from there to the other.

2) The css part:

```
/* svg > g > g > g > path  (exact path) */
svg path:hover {
    stroke-opacity: 1;
}
```

This will set the opacity of the line to 1 if a line is hovered with the mouse. The tricky part again is getting to the circle endpoint. But that may be fixable with the options object used in the draw function.

3) Have a deep look at the annotaion options and such for the line chart.

I've tried some variations, but haven't found an exact solution yet.

https://developers.google.com/chart/interactive/docs/gallery/linechart#configuration-options

x) Hypothetically, we could combine all of the above by having the css color the opacity of the line, then also have a mouseover handler on the line, that will grab the correct circle, and then manually trigger a mouseover on the circle, so we can trigger the changes we can make using the annotation options.

Unless there's some draw options I've missed, this is my only atm idea to get exactly what the OP descibes.

Comment: Thank you Shilly for your deep search. As you can see, it's not easy to find a working solution and that's why I thought StackOverflow was the best suited place to ask for such help. My mistake being to give freedom of choice on the library. I'll see your answer and come back to you :)

Comment: For your info, using your answer as a base, I was able to reproduce this code : https://jsfiddle.net/7nk1odsy/2/. From my point of view, it's missing the possibility to also "glow" the blue line when hovering the red/orange one and if I add values instead of nulls for the "forecasts" columns, the blue line takes those values instead of the "Sales" column (when hovering the dots).

Answer (score 1):

If you have time learn D3(Data Driven Documents).  It's a very powerful open source free charting library. I've been working with it off and on over the past few months and it can do what you're asking. Here is the [homepage](https://d3js.org/). If you're just making a line chart or multiple line charts it shouldn't take too long to get this done. Here is a [free book](https://leanpub.com/d3-t-and-t-v4) I used to learn the basics.

Comment: Thank you for your post. I know D3 by name only (never tested it directly). I was hoping to find a good library like ChartJS or Google Chart that would already provide what I was looking for.